# Is there any standard for naming RS-485 tty devices/device aliases in Linux?

Tags: devices, serial-port

I know, that there are some standards in tty naming.

There is ttyUSBx for USB to serial converters, ttySx for RS-232, ttyAMAx on ARM devices, but I can't find anything about conventions in RS-485 port naming.

I'm preparing linux distribution for custom ARM-based machine and I want to name things properly.

The question is: **are there any conventions in tty device naming for RS-485 serial ports?**

Comment: As far as I can tell, it looks like the convention might be the same (ttySx) for serial devices. That being said, it would be relatively easy to create a udev rule (or rules) that use a more intuitive naming convention.

Comment: @CalebReister there seems to be no way to check from userspace if the serial protocol is RS232 or RS485. We can check it in BIOS but there is no way to dynamically check it from applications. If there is a way that you are aware of, please let me know.

Comment: @CalebReister And this is what I wanted to do. Create udev rule, but I was looking for some convention.

Comment: @Kamil I don't think there's a *standard* defining what convention to use. The RS-485 defines the electrical interface, not the protocol, which is what matters to the OS. However, you may find this helpful: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-10.html

Comment: @CalebReister Thanks, I have read that. But with /dev/ttyUSB we can say that USB is also just kind of carrier, but actual protocol is serial... Finally I gave up and I created udev rules to make /dev/ttyDIFF* or something like that.